# Create Android Game UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I Developed An android game Using OpenGlEs

Now I want to Create its UI And Main Menu Items, Im currently using relative Layouts to create the menu, Buttons and their Animation, But since i have many items in my menu, it is trouble to work with,

What is the best way to implement GUI in android? should i keep Going with layouts or work with Canvas and SurfaceView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your choice if you just want to choose between XML based and custom Views.

- XML based layouts easy to design,  so you can quickly implement those, You can have basic animations with them but no complete control over the drawing mechanism.  Straight forward control to Inputs.
- While Canvas and SurfaceView approach requires you to do all the drawings and then handle Inputs,  this way you can have full control over drawings but it adds more complexity to code side.

You can choose what suits your need , on the other hand, if you have too many views *ie* too many button etc. You can simply try `switch` statement and applying distinct width/height to each element `or` use `onTouchListener` to get coordinates of touch and respond (supposing you already know coordinatesbof all views) hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easy way to create UIs for Android, Eclipse and Android Studio both provide a WYSIWYG UI creator. I have not used it yet but it should be fine for layouts which do not need significant customization. If all you're doing is creating simple menus/text/buttons then this should serve you fine, no need to use anything more complex than the Views/Layouts provided by the Android API.